# x11 xGetImage BadMatch Error

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xorg

I am trying to make a simple program that will dump the current screen and convert it to a png image. However, I am currently getting the error "X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)", which appears to be caused by the XGetImage. Looking through the documentation, this appears to be caused by either of the two:

BadMatch -  An InputOnly window is used as a Drawable.

BadMatch -  Some argument or pair of arguments has the correct type and range but fails to match in some other way required by the request.

I assume is has to do with the first one, however I am not sure. If it does how would I be able to get a dump of the screen?

This is the snippet of the code giving the error:

```
Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

Window root = DefaultRootWindow(d);

int windowHeight = XDisplayHeight (d, 0);
int windowWidth = XDisplayWidth(d, 0);


// Get dump of screen
XImage *image = XGetImage(d, root, 0, 0, windowHeight, windowWidth, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "width" and "height" arguments are in the wrong order, swap them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I can't believe I didn't realize this  myself! I was too caught up on the fact I thought it was a problem with the window.